# How do we create an array of structure, which has the flexible array as its last field?

Tags: c

Let's say we have:

```
struct A {
  int i;
  char c[1];
};
```

Usually I would use `malloc()` to create an instance of A, like:

```
#define LEN 10

struct A *my_A = malloc(sizeof(A) + LEN * sizeof(char));
```

But this would not work if I try to create an array of A

Comment: The last member of that structure is *not* a flexible array member.  That looks like the struct hack, which inspired flexible array members, but was never itself standard.

Comment: There is one linux call which actually stores structs with flexible array member in one, consecutive, single chunk of memory and uses custom accessor functions to iterate over the structs. But I can't remember the name...

Answer (score 6):

A `struct` with a flexible array member cannot be a member of an array.  This is explicitly stated in section 6.7.2.1p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
>   function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
>   itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of  itself),  except 
>   that  the  last  member  of  a  structure  with  more  than  one 
>   named  member may  have  incomplete  array  type;  **such  a  structure 
>   (and  any  union  containing,  possibly recursively, a member that is
>   such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element
>   of an array.**

What you would need to do instead is declare the struct with a pointer instead of a flexible array member, and allocate space for each instance.

For example:

```
struct A {
  int i;
  char *c;
};

struct A arr[100];

for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    arr[i].c = malloc(LEN);
}
```

Comment: Or they could use an array of pointers to structs with flexible array members, each independently allocated.

Answer (score 1):

We don't.

One of the key characteristics of an array is that you know the offset between one element and the next, and you can't do that if the elements are variably-sized.

What you can create is an array of pointers to your flexibly-sized type. How each of the pointed-to objects is allocated is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do what you have shown in your code just using a custom allocation / array iteration mechanism (you won't be able to use the default [] operator, though, because it determines the offset based on the size of the member), but I think that you don't want to do that.

In C/C++, a "flexible" array is just a pointer to an allocated piece of memory in the heap. What you would want to do in this case is this:

```
struct A {
  int i;
  char* c; // A pointer to an array
};

#define LEN 10
#define FLEX_ARRAY_LEN 20

struct A* my_A = malloc(sizeof(A) * LEN);
// initialize each array member
for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
  // allocating new memory chunk for the flexible array of ith member
  my_A[i].c = malloc(sizeof(char) * FLEX_ARRAY_LEN);
}
```

Comment: No, in C, a "[flexible array member](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18)" is a special feature that structure types may have.  But the OP actually appears to be using its pre-standardization predecessor, the so-called "struct hack".  In either case, although this *is* related to dynamically-allocated memory, it's not the same thing as a "flexible array" the way you seem to be using that term.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Okay, thanks! I just thought that OP does not know about heap allocation, and so I skipped the "flexible array member" explanation and then proceeded to dynamic memory. Also why would you do that if it is possible to simply declare that the struct member "c" has LEN size?

Comment: Usually you *wouldn't* use flexible array members.  But they can be convenient in cases where you cannot put a reasonable bound on the number of array elements you'll want, yet prefer to have only one object to manage instead of two.  Don't worry if you don't see a practical application, for although it was inspired by real-world (mis)usage, you'll be just fine if you never write a single program that relies on this feature.